# UI does not update after object is added to ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, entity-framework-core, maui

I'm creating an application with a book library. I can add books to the library and they appear correctly when I rebuild the application. However I want the book to appear immediately on the screen after adding them and thought of doing so by using a observable collection.

My collection view:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Books}" Margin="36, 20" Grid.Row="1">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <Border StrokeThickness="3" Margin="0, 0, 0, 4">
                  <Border.Stroke>
                       <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
                                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.1" />
                                <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource Gray950}" Offset="1.0" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Stroke>
                        <Grid HeightRequest="84">
                            <Image Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding ThumbnailSource}"/>
                            <FlexLayout JustifyContent="Center" Direction="Column" HeightRequest="84" Margin="16">
                                <FlexLayout.Background>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#80000000" Offset="0.4"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="0.9"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </FlexLayout.Background>
                                <Label FontSize="20" TextColor="White" Text="{Binding Title}" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                            </FlexLayout>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

My view model:

```
namespace eBooks.ViewModel
{
    public partial class LibraryViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public LibraryViewModel()
        {
            BookService.OnBooksChanged += RefreshLibrary;
            RefreshLibrary();
        }

        public void RefreshLibrary(List<Book> books = null)
        {
            using var db = new BooksContext();
            _books = new ObservableCollection<Book>(db.Books);
        }

        [ObservableProperty]
        ObservableCollection<Book> _books;
    }
}
```

My Book model

```
namespace eBooks.Models
{
    [Table("Books")]
    public class Book
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public double Progress { get; set; }
        public string ThumbnailData { get; set; }

        public string AudioData { get; set; }
        public string ThumbnailFormat { get; set; }
        public string AudioFormat { get; set; }

        private byte[] _thumbnailData = null;

        public ImageSource ThumbnailSource
        {
            get
            {
                if (_thumbnailData == null || _thumbnailData.Length == 0 && ThumbnailData.Length != 0)
                    _thumbnailData = Convert.FromBase64String(ThumbnailData);

                return ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(_thumbnailData));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My service that handles actions for my EF Core database layer:

```
namespace eBooks.Services
{
    public class BookService
    {
        public delegate void BooksChanged(List<Book> books);
        public static event BooksChanged OnBooksChanged;

        public void Add(Book book)
        {
            using var db = new BooksContext();
            db.Books.Add(book);
            db.SaveChanges();
            OnBooksChanged?.Invoke(db.Books.ToList());
        }

        public void Delete(int id)
        {
            using var db = new BooksContext();
            db.Books.Remove(db.Books.Single(book => book.Id == id));
            db.SaveChanges();
            OnBooksChanged?.Invoke(db.Books.ToList());
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried adding a 'refreshlibrary' method that runs when the `OnBooksChanged` event is invoked in the book service as you can see in the code above. By adding a breakpoint to the method I can see that it contains the newly added book after adding it, however the UI still does not show the book.

Comment: *actions for my EF Core database* - EF Core is ***NOT*** a database - it's just a database **access** layer; the database is Oracle, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, MySQL or whatever else you might be connecting to ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case `ObservableCollection` has no advantage over a simple `List`. The advantage of an `ObservableCollection` is that it will notify changes to the controls it's bound to, if you **manipulate** the contents of the collection. Here, you are not manipulating the contents of `_books`, you are assigning **a new instance** every time. So let's say at the beginning you have `(Book1, Book2)` in `_books`, let's name this collection `A`, if `Book3` gets added to your database, you will assign **a new collection** `(Book1, Book2, Book3)` to `_books`, let's name the new collection `B`. Note that you haven't added `Book3` to `A` anywhere. Now, your `CollectionView` is still bound to `A` which has not been changed, hence no update notifications will be received. All you need to do is to make sure the `CollectionView` re-evaluates its binding and is bound to `B`. There are a couple of ways to do this:

1. Set the generated property instead of the backing field, as it will automatically call `OnPropertyChanged`:

```cs
public void RefreshLibrary(List<Book> books = null)
{
    using var db = new BooksContext();
    Books = new ObservableCollection<Book>(db.Books);
}
```

2. Call `OnPropertyChanged`:

```cs
public void RefreshLibrary(List<Book> books = null)
{
    using var db = new BooksContext();
    _books = new ObservableCollection<Book>(db.Books);
    OnPropertyChanged("Books");
}
```

Again, you can safely change the type of `_books` to `List<Book>` as it's not manipulated anywhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Changing it to the generated property did the job